# Does Alter Self work with shape shifting?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, lycanthropy

I used to play a [Lythari Elf](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Lythari_(5e_Subrace)#Lythari) Mage in 3.5e and now I want to play a Lythari Elf Sorcerer. Lythari Elves are special for their lycanthropic transformation powers:

> *The lythari are a subrace of elves who can transform into wolves. Unlike most werewolves, they can transform at will and keep their minds while in wolf form.*

— From [Wikipedia's description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elf_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons))

I am curious if I cast Alter Self to appear a size or two bigger and then shifted into a wolf form, would the spell still be active making me appear akin to a dire wolf or winter wolf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Alter Self does not allow you to appear to be a different size.

This is stated in the text of the *alter self* spell.

> ... [you] can't appear as a creature of a different size than you...

If you did cast it on yourself and the effect continued to apply to you in your wolf form, you would continue to appear the same size as you are in your wolf form, which would still be Medium.